# Trying to understand this useRef behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm a beginner in React and I'm using chatGPT to help me with the studies. I've asked it to do a code using useRef for storing the previous value of a number. Here's the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const PrevCountExample = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const prevCountRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    prevCountRef.current = count; // Store the previous state
    // Do something with the current and previous state
    console.log(count, prevCountRef.current);
  }, [count]);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current Count: {count}</p>
      <p>Previous Count: {prevCountRef.current}</p>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PrevCountExample
```

The line

```
console.log(count, prevCountRef.current);
```

was included by me. Now, I see that count and prevCountRef get the same value inside of useEffect, but the values printed inside of the `<p>` tags are always one in difference (count being prevCountRef + 1). Could someone tell me why is this working like this? What's the order of events here?

Comment: The error is the logic. You're writing value to console after changing it in useEffect, not before. move this line `prevCountRef.current = count` and put it after the `console.log...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, `useRef` does not cause render. `useState` does.
Anytime `useState`, or other state of the component changes, it tells everywhere it has changed, which cause the render, to display the updated data.
with `useRef` you can change it as much as you want, and nobody will now, no render will happen because of `useRef` change.

- `handleIncrement` is called, updating count to count + 1.
- The component re-renders, showing the new count value.
- The `useEffect` hook runs, updating `prevCountRef.current` to the new `count` value.

`useEffect` runs after the render has been committed to the screen, that is why prevCountRef.current still holds the previous value of count from the last render. but updating useRef does not cause render. so deep inside useRef changed, but nobody knows about it. your component still shows the previous value

Comment: I get it now! Thanks for the clarification. However, I was seeing this video by Kyle:
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2ypzz6gJm0)
@4:15 he writes a piece of code that makes use of useRef to keep track of how many times the component was rendered, and there the useRef variable isn't one behind. Wouldn't it be the same logic as the example I posted earlier? Sorry I can't paste the code here, it's too long for a comment.